Kafka Log (message) removal does not seem to work
I acknowledge many similar questions on SO (eg: https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/issues/366), but my issue remains. Hence
Context: I have a use case where large number of http post requests are hitting a php url. kafka is to collect data from all these individual requests, and process them in batches. For this, I have a basic 'producer' code in the target url, and that part is working. Messages are coming in.
Requirement: Once a given message is consumed (relevant data gets saved to a db), I want to delete this message, to save disk space.
Setup: Below is my docker-compose.yml
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    
    networks:
      - default
  

  
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - default

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1:delete --config=retention.ms=20000"
      # KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS: 10000
      KAFKA_LOG_ROLL_MS: 10000
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 5000
      KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: delete
      # KAFKA_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES: 3000
      KAFKA_LOG_CLEANER_DELETE_RETENTION_MS: 5000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - default

What I expect:
While 10 seconds is a very short period to remove the logs, this is only for testing. Say, I run the consumer at time t=0, I can print all the incoming messages. So far so good. I tried consumers with and without commit(). In either case, I would expect that after 10 seconds, If I run a consumer to access messages from the starting offset of 0, Eg:
$topic->consumeStart(KAFKA_PARTITION, 0);

I would expect these messages to be non existent as per my ENV VARIABLE SETTINGS in yml. But they are always there. Never gets deleted.
Note: There is plenty of posts with similar questions, and I tried pretty much everything that these posts are recommending, but with no success.
My questions:

Am I understanding it correctly, that with my yml settings, I can expect these messages to be REALLY deleted?
If so, what am I doing wrong?


Turns out the issue was the environmental variable names were incorrect. bitnami/kafka has an _CFG in the env var names.
Eg KAFKA_CFG_LOG_RETENTION_MS 

With that, it is working as expected.

You cannot in general expect Kafka messages to ever be deleted.  Sometimes, according to the retention settings, messages may be deleted, but you should never count on them being removed from the topic.
Note that messages in Kafka are deleted by the retention mechanism without regard for whether they've been consumed, so if you found settings that would ensure prompt deletion it would be very likely that some messages from the producer would get deleted from Kafka before getting to the database.
For what you're trying to do, using a message queue that's not Kafka is a much better idea.

Thanks, After some initial research, I picked kafka to work with, but I could always go back. But given the time I spent on this, I wish to atleast learn and understand it before leaving. On that regard,  if the retention mechanism is what it says, then is it not reasonable to expect that if I set the retention time , my consumer should not see older messages?

If you continue producing to the topic and wait long enough, eventually Kafka will purge messages older then the retention window, but there's not really a hard guarantee on when they will be purged.
